# Identifying last subscribed event of EventHandler c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, event-handling, asynccallback

I have a silver light application, where a service method is called asynchronously. I am required to identify the last subscribed event and perform a specific operation. For an example like below.

```
foreach(var proj in lstProj)
{
 ServiceApi.CreateTemplateInfoAsync(proj.Id, proj.Name);
 ServiceApi.CreateTemplateInfoCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(ServiceApi_CreateTemplateInfoCompleted);
}
```

The above implementation iterates for 10 times for instance, I would like to know the last subscribed event and perform an operation.

```
void ServiceApi_CreateTemplateInfoCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                LogErrorInfo(m_ClassName, "CreateTemplateInfoCompleted", e.Error.InnerException.Message, true);
            }
            UtilityApp.ServiceApi.CreateTemplateInfoCompleted -= ServiceApi_CreateTemplateInfoCompleted;

//Check a condition here to know there are no more subscribed events and do an operation.
If(no more subscriber for CreateTemplateInfoCompleted)
{
//Do something.
}
        }
```

I have seen this can be obtained from `CreateTemplateInfoCompleted.GetInvocationList()`, However I don’t see that method displayed in intellisense or available. Please provide suggestions.

Comment: Since in the context of the class declaring the event, the `CreateTemplateInfoCompleted` identifier refers to the event field and not the event itself, you can in fact use the `GetInvocationList()` to determine the subscribers for the event. But why? The code example you posted makes no sense; subscribing a new event handler every time you perform the async operation? If you have ten operations, and you manage the initiate all ten before any complete, your event handler will be invoked 100 times! This question needs some serious clarification if you want a truly good answer.

Comment: I precised the scenario like the code above, nevertheless its not the same like in my code. New events are subscribed from multiple methods which run asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

`GetInvocationList()` is a method of MulticastDelegate which is available only if your class owns the event. Other classes can only subscribe/unsubscribe to the event.

In your case, I would suggest keeping and additional list of delegates used to subscribe to that event and keep that list in sync with your operations. Something like:`List<EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>>` and each time you subscribe to that event, add your delegate into this list then work with it. (be careful about synchronization issues if you're using async)

The best way though is to think about a better design for the whole approach.